# What happens if a variable does not get a value?

Tags: java, class

Hey just wondering since I don't have access to a Java program on a Guest computer.
What would happen if a class has two variables, (width and height) and one variable does not get an instance but the other variable does. Would this output to NullPointer? Or would there just be no ouput with no errors?

So this code for example:

```
class Box{
   public int width, height;
}
```

So for the instances;

(Anyone saying this a duplicate question, the other question doesn't ask if this turns into error, but instead says what the default value is. I want to know if it turns into an error or just no output.

```
Box r;
r.height= 5;
```

So the width gets no instance;
Would this output in error/ or just no output with no errors?

Comment: `Box r ;` is wrong. It should have been `Box r = new Box();`

Answer (score 0):

`width` and `height` are instance variables. When you create an instance of the class, Java will assign default values to instance variables. For int, default value is 0. So if you create the Box instance first, there will be no errors

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I needed to know.